# Cannot install SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2012 Standard and got this message:

```
SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

The resource 'Microsoft.SQL.Chainer.PackageData.Package.xml' failed to load
from 'E:\PCUSOURCE\x64\Microsoft.SQL.Chainer.PackageData.Package.dll'.

Error code 0x85650003.
```

I applied the latest updates, but I still get this error. What should I do?

---

Summary text below:

```
--------------------
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Passed
  Exit code (Decimal):           0
  Start time:                    2015-01-28 18:18:18
  End time:                      2015-01-28 18:18:37
  Requested action:              RunRules

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  WINDOWS191
  Machine processor count:       2
  OS version:                    Future Windows Version
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2012 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2012
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       11
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         C:\en_sql_server_2012_enterprise_edition_with_sp1_x64_dvd_1227976\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Enterprise

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        RunRules
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
  ENU:                           true
  FEATURES:                      
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTANCENAME:                  <empty>
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  RULES:                         SCCCheckRules
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  X86:                           false

 Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150128_181817\ConfigurationFile.ini

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

There are no scenario-specific rules.

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150128_181817\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Comment: please add contents of summary.txt in question this link would help you locate it.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702%28v=sql.110%29.aspx plus be specific are you installing on windows 8 or windows server 2012

Comment: Its quite possible package has got corrupted during extraction but to confirm that I need to have a look at `summary.txt and details.txt` file

Comment: Some more details here: http://justpaste.it/j5dr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see lot of Cannot be found messages in errorlog like

```
(01) 2015-01-28 18:13:57 Slp: Sco: File 'E:\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\SQLSysClrTypes\x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi' does not exist
(01) 2015-01-28 18:13:57 Slp: Sco: File 'E:\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\SQLSysClrTypes\SQLSysClrTypes.msi' does not exist
(01) 2015-01-28 18:13:57 Slp: Sco: File 'E:\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSSetup\x86\vs_setup.msi' does not exist
(01) 2015-01-28 18:13:57 Slp: Sco: File 'E:\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSSetup\vs_setup.msi' does not exist
(01) 2015-01-28 18:13:57 Slp: Sco: File 'E:\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSIntSetup\x86\vs_setup.msi' does not exist
(01) 2015-01-28 18:13:57 Slp: Sco: File 'E:\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSIntSetup\vs_setup.msi' does not exist
(01) 2015-01-28 18:13:57 Slp: Sco: File 'E:\x64\setup\x64\unused' does not exist
(01) 2015-01-28 18:13:57 Slp: Sco: File 'E:\x64\setup\unused' does not exist
(01) 2015-01-28 18:13:57 Slp: Sco: File 'E:\x64\setup\x86\unused' does not exist
(01) 2015-01-28 18:13:57 Slp: Sco: File 'E:\x64\setup\unused' does not exist
(01) 2015-01-28 18:13:57 Slp: Sco: File 'E:\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\sql2008support\x64\SqlSupport.msi' does not exist
(01) 2015-01-28 18:13:57 Slp: Sco: File 'E:\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\sql2008support\SqlSupport.msi' does not exist
(01) 2015-01-28 18:13:57 Slp: Sco: File 'E:\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\x64\SqlDom.msi' does not exist
(01) 2015-01-28 18:13:57 Slp: Sco: File 'E:\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\SqlDom.msi' does not exist
```

This makes me think that the package is nt complete and while you were converting ISO file to executable file all files related to installation were not extracted.

You are trying to install SQL Server 2012 enterprise and Windows 8 machine not windows server. Its not supported on windows 8 please see [hardware and software requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) but it wont stop you from installation.

If you are installing SQL Server 2012 on windows 8 you MUST read [this support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2681562) before proceeding